# Ruby gem install fails because it can't find openssl installed by Homebrew

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, homebrew

When I try to install a Ruby gem that depends on openssl, I'm getting (among other log lines):

```
fatal error: 'openssl/sha.h' file not found
#include <openssl/sha.h>
```

What is the right way to install it, if I have openssl installed via Homebrew at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1` and at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3`.

Comment: Hi! Try that: https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/jekyll-install-fatal-error-openssl-ssl-h-file-not-found-macos/7660

Comment: @VasilyKolesnikov doesn't work :(

Comment: Oh, sad :(
OS X and Ruby versions? Gem name? I've also have both versions of openssl on my laptop, so I could check the gem installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it worked:

```
$ gem install eventmachine -- --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl\@1.1/1.1.1u/
```

The directory `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1u/` is where Homebrew installed OpenSSL 1.1. Also works with `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/`.

A canonical method, as I understand, is the following:

```
$ rvm pkg install openssl
$ rvm reinstall ruby-3.2.1 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
$ gem install eventmachine
```

If it's desired to make Ruby use openssl installed by Homebrew:

```
$ brew install openssl@1.1
$ rvm reinstall ruby-3.2.1 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl\@1.1/1.1.1u
$ gem install eventmachine
```

I had to put this into `~/.profile` (before running `rvm reinstall`!):

```
export CPPFLAGS="${CPPFLAGS} -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1u/include"
```